# How to display specific head tag in the index.html of a VueJS project?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to display specific tags in the index.html file only when I'm in production mode, but specifically in the /public/index.html file.

I saw a few questions on SO regarding how to know if we are in dev/prod, but for Node, not inside the index.html file, which seems to have its own rendering template.

Comment: Is your project managed by Vue CLI ?

Comment: Yes it's managed by Vue CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Vue CLI or Webpack + HtmlWebpackPlugin directly...

If you are using Vue CLI to manage your project, Vue CLI has preconfigured Webpack and HtmlWebpackPlugin specifically with [all client-side ENV variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#interpolation) available to (default) [Lodash template engine](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template)

So you just need to add something like this into your `index.html` template:

```html
<% if(NODE_ENV === "production") { %>
 ...insert any HTML here
<% } %>
```

If you are NOT using Vue CLI, you must [configure HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) in `webpack.config.js` to make `NODE_ENV` variable available in the template:

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      templateParameters: {
        'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
      }
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you !