# How to load external script file in index.html differently on build mode? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to load external script file only on a production mode.
At first, I tried to use NODE_ENV, but found it impossible.
So I compared URL using window.location.host as shown below.

Isn't there a more sophisticated way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<script>
  window.addEventListner('load', function(event) {
  let host = window.location.host;
  if (host.match('some production URL')) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', '~.js');
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  </div id="app></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your build environment? Plain Webpack or Vue CLI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display specific head tag in the index.html of a VueJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904036/how-to-display-specific-head-tag-in-the-index-html-of-a-vuejs-project)